# How to get notification as Notifications not as onGoing

Tags: android, android-notifications

This is my code:

```
Notification n = new Notification();
n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
n.tickerText="test";
n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

Intent dummyIntent = new Intent();
dummyIntent.setAction("dummy");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, dummyIntent, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(c, "test","test", pi);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)c.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   nm.notify(1, n);
```

I want to put this as notifications not as onGoing.
But this Notification is indicated as onGoing?
Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can Build Notifications on this way, this is the new method for creating Notifications and let you customize them better than the old one as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html).

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
                           .setContentText("Text")
                           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                           .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                           .setOngoing(false)
                           .setTicker("Ticker Text");
```

With `setOngoing()` you can set it to `true` or `false`.